# What is the sort key in IE's Favorites menu?

Tags: internet-explorer, bookmarks

I have few hundreds of bookmarks in Internet Explorer (currently IE10). When I open **Favorites** menu on the menu bar I can see **the bookmarks appearing not exactly in order I added them**, but their order is 'slightly' mixed. It appears random to me, I cannot figure out the sort key.

Similarly, after I add a bookmark, it won't necessarily appear at the end of the list, but sorted alphabetically among the items at the bottom of the list.

I know 3rd party tools or other browsers can manage the bookmarks better, but currently I'm interested in this problem. I often work in IE and its **Favorites** menu and sidebar are quite handy – except of that strange sort order.

[image: Favorites menu screenshot]

On the screenshot of the dropdown menu, items are not in order as they were added, recently added item (30 minutes ago) is highlighted by blue. It is not at the end of the list. The item at end of the list was actually added 4 days ago. It looks like alphabetical ordering has been applied when adding recent (blue-marked) item.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but the sorting is controlled by the registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MenuOrder\Favorites. As for the algorithm, *how* the items are sorted, I do not know.

Comment: @PatrickS. - Thank you and +1 for the hint. I found that sort option is available by right-clicking any bookmark or folder in *Favorites* menu. I'd like to prefer sorting by time but for someone who simply wants to re-sort bookmarks alphabetically, this can be definitely an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conclusion to date is:

- sort algorithm is not known
- alpahabetical sort can be invoked manually using context menu: [image]